# Configure a local area network for laptops and(or) raspberry

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a ubuntu laptop and raspberry pi and router. Would it be possible to create a local area network to connect them. There is no need to connect to the internet but have to ensure laptop and raspberry can connect each other like using ssh.

Looks like creating a local area network. But quit suspect and confused if it is possible. If it is, can share me how to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your router already has a LAN - one that works for all devices connected to the router.  Why do you want to complicate your setup and not use the router's LAN?

Comment: Hi, Thomas. Basically laptop and raspberry are all installed on a robot. Sometimes the SSH connection by wifi are not stable. So i'm thinking it is possible to setup a local network so that laptop and raspberry can communicate between each other by ethernet. Then the connection might be more stable and fast. Might be no need to use router? I thought if use router, i might have a local wireless then i can use another laptop to control..